# React component not resetting state when using Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a React component that doesn't seem to be resetting its initial state correctly. I'm using Object.assign() to make sure that passed down props have all fields (to retro-fit for legacy database entries where keys might be undefined).

newProfile is a complete profile (with headline field), and legacyProfile is an entry from before the headline field was added. Why/how is the component passing legacyProfile somehow keeping some data from another instance (the component passing newProfile), and how can I prevent this to make sure I always start with a fresh profileInitialState?

```js
const profileInitialState = {
  name: '',
  title: '',
  headline: '',
  bio: ''
}

class Bio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editingProfile: Object.assign(profileInitialState, this.props.profile)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { profile } = this.props;
    const { editingProfile } = this.state;
    
    console.log(profile); // props profile has correct info
    console.log(editingProfile); // state profile takes on old values
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{editingProfile.name}</h1>
        <h2>{editingProfile.title}</h2>
        <h3>{editingProfile.headline}</h3>
        <p>{editingProfile.bio}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const newProfile = {
  name: 'Test 1',
  title: 'Title 1',
  headline: 'Headline 1',
  bio: 'Bio 1'
}

const legacyProfile = {
  name: 'Test 2',
  title: 'Title 2',
  bio: 'Bio 2'
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
  <Bio profile={newProfile} />
  <Bio profile={legacyProfile} />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.assign` will assign own enumerable properties from all arguments 2nd and above into the object in the 1st argument. So

```
editingProfile: Object.assign(profileInitialState, this.props.profile)
```

*mutates* `profileInitialState`.

That line is similar to

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(this.props.profile)) {
  profileInitialState[key] = val;
}
```

As a result, the second time that line runs, results from the first may still exist in `profileInitialState`.

Instead, use

```
editingProfile: Object.assign({}, profileInitialState, this.props.profile)
```

to create an entirely new object:

```js
const profileInitialState = {
  name: '',
  title: '',
  headline: '',
  bio: ''
}

class Bio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editingProfile: Object.assign({}, profileInitialState, this.props.profile)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { profile } = this.props;
    const { editingProfile } = this.state;
    
    console.log(profile); // props profile has correct info
    console.log(editingProfile); // state profile takes on old values
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{editingProfile.name}</h1>
        <h2>{editingProfile.title}</h2>
        <h3>{editingProfile.headline}</h3>
        <p>{editingProfile.bio}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const newProfile = {
  name: 'Test 1',
  title: 'Title 1',
  headline: 'Headline 1',
  bio: 'Bio 1'
}

const legacyProfile = {
  name: 'Test 2',
  title: 'Title 2',
  bio: 'Bio 2'
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
  <Bio profile={newProfile} />
  <Bio profile={legacyProfile} />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
editingProfile: { ...profileInitialState, ...this.props.profile }
```

Comment: You rock. Thank you for the clear code and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign copies from the source (second argument) to the target (first argument).

What is your target object? The profileInitialState you declared outside of the Bio class.

In the first run through, you're modifying your 'default'. In the second run through, it uses the new default, which as you've noticed, has that filled-in headline property now.